# Set watermark (text) in laravel excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I am using laravel Maatwebsite\Excel. I am trying to set a text as watermark. Also using form view of Maatwebsite-Excel. But not working

```
 namespace App\Exports;

class DraftSalaryEnhancementReportExport implements FromView, WithEvents
{

public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
            $event->setWatermarkText('This is a watermark');
         }
      ]
}
}
```